# Effects of Vitamin K2-7 on existing plaque

Tags: calcium, plaque, vitamin-k

There are quite a few studies on the impact of vitamin K2 supplementation on calcification of the arteries.

For example:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4566462/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7071387/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6775440/

and many more...

All of them seem to imply that vitamin K2 supplementation seems to reduce, or at the minimum prevent increase, of artery calcification.

However, none of them cover the topic of stable plaque in the arteries. Since the plaque is stable as it is calcified, and the studies show a reduction of the calcification, the question that comes up is: could supplementation lead to plaque destabilization and eventually rupture.

One link seems to imply this is not the case: https://prevmedhealth.com/vitamin-k2-can-it-remove-plaque/
but it's more like general information without any real explanation.

Has this question been studied somewhere? is there any existing literature discussion plaque stability vs. K2 supplementation?